# Python ftplib add new line to txt file with str

Tags: python, ftplib

I have a txt file `test.txt` in a ftp server and I want to add new line to this file I'have try this but this doen't work.

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect(host=HOST, port=PORT)
ftp.login(user=USER, passwd=PASSWD)

new_line = '\n this is a new line'
ftp.storlines('STOR test.txt', new_line)
```

I get this error :

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline'
```

Comment: *this doen't work* this is very vague description, can you add more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of `ftp.storlines` is expected to be a file object and you have passed a string. The error exactly says that the string `new_line` is not a file object because is has not `readlines` method.

What you want is probably to use the `transfercmd` method and the `APPE` command:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect(host=HOST, port=PORT)
ftp.login(user=USER, passwd=PASSWD)
ftp.sendcmd('TYPE I')

new_line = '\n this is a new line'
s = ftp.transfercmd('APPE test.txt')
s.send(new_line.encode())
s.close()
ftp.quit()
```